# How to create a comma separated tag list in Docpad?

Tags: coffeescript, docpad

The tags for a post can be accessed within the post like this (using embedded Coffeescript):

```
<div class="tags">
Tags:
  <ul>
    <% for tag in @document.tags: %>
      <li><a class="tag_item" href="<%= @getTagUrl(tag) %>"><%= tag %></a></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
```

This generates an unordered list of the tags for this specific topic, like this:

Tags:

- tag1
- tag2
- tag3

How can I generate the list of tags as comma separated values on a single line, like this:

Tags: tag1, tag2, tag3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do it like this on my blog:

```
<div class="post-tags">
    Posted In: <%- ("<a href='#{@getTagUrl(tag)}'>#{tag}</a>" for tag in @tags).join(', ') %>
</div>
```

Note, @getTagUrl comes from the docpad-plugin-tagging plugin.  If you don't want hyperlinks to a page for each tag, you could simplify this to the following:

```
<div class="post-tags">
    Posted In: <%- (tag for tag in @tags).join(', ') %>
</div>
```

Comment: Excellent, here is the syntax I used:

`Tags: <%- (id for id in @document.tags).join(', ') %>`

Comment: I spent ages looking for the [nice] syntax to do this, thanks